# Problema con variable numerica de datos de gapminder

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo comunidad, tengo un problema con datos sobre ingreso per cápita descargados directamente desde la página web de gapminder; esta base tiene datos para todos los países desde 1799 hasta 2049; no obstante, para hacer más fácil mi consulta solo comparto los datos desde 2020 a 2022. Lo que sucede es que ciertos valores vienen en formato numérico, por ejemplo, tres mil quinientos cincuenta (3550), y otros vienen con un caracter (k) que representa que está en miles, es decir, cincuenta y un mil seiscientos (51.6k); cómo puedo hacer para acomodar este últimpo tipo de valores, 51.6k -> 51600. sin afectar el resto de números de cada año que sí están en el formato numérico correcto.

De antemano muchísimas gracias por la ayuda que se me pueda prestar. Comparto acontinuación el subconjunto de datos para revisar:

```
income3 <- structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", 
                                      "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
                                      "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Burundi", "Belgium", "Benin", 
                                      "Burkina Faso", "Bangladesh", "Bulgaria", "Bahrain", "Bahamas", 
                                      "Bosnia and Herzegovina"), 
                          `2020` = c("1950", "5980", "14.3k", "55.1k", "65.1k", "21.5k", "13.4k", "17.7k", "50.2k", "53.9k", 
                                     "14.4k", "728", "51.6k", "3440", "2240", "4990", "23.4k", "43.9k", 
                                     "32.2k", "15.3k"), 
                          `2021` = c("1990", "5980", "14.7k", "56.5k", "65.2k", "22.1k", "13.6k", "18.6k", "51.9k", "55k", 
                                     "14.6k", "733", "52.4k", "3550", "2280", "5280", "24.3k", "44.5k", "33.7k", "15.7k"), 
                          `2022` = c("2040", "6000", "15.1k", "56.9k", "66.3k", "22.6k", "14.1k", "19.4k", "52.5k", "56.4k", 
                                     "14.8k", "744", "52.9k", "3660", "2320", "5590", "25.6k", "44.9k", "34.7k", "16.1k"
                                     )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                            ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución estilo tidyverse es usar `across()` para aplicar **una misma función** a **varias variables**

Usaremos la función gsub() para reemplazar las "k" por "00" y luego reemplazar los "." por nada "" para luego darle formato de numero con `as.numeric()`

Te dejo dos formas en que se puede aplicar a las **columnas de interes**

```
income3 %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = !country, .fns  = ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", gsub("k", "00", .)))))

income3 %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = 2:4, .fns  = ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", gsub("k", "00", .)))))
```

Comment: Bastian Andres, muchísimas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, me sirvió perfectamente, saludos